# Explain routing decision

Tags: networking, routing, tunneling

On my linux server, I have the following routing table:

```
$ ip ro
default via 172.28.127.254 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.3.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.3.2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.28.96.0/19 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.107.175 metric 600
```

Based on it I would guess that, if I was to try to reach IP 8.8.8.8, linux would do so through the default gateway `172.28.127.254` behind interface `wlp0s20f3`. However, this is not the case:

```
$ ip ro get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 dev tun0 table 205 src 10.8.3.2 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Please explain, why is default gateway not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [policy-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) in place, as hinted by `table 205` in the routing decision.

You'd get more information by checking at least the output of:

- `ip rule`

  which will have one or multiple rules in addition to the default three with preferences 0, 32766 and 32767. The additional rule(s) will reference at least one additional routing table: `table 205`. Usually the additional rule(s) depend(s) on something else than destination (since this is already covered by simple use of routes so is rarely used in a rule), but could even depend on nothing (reading just `from all lookup 205`: acting as simple override) and if matching will then select an other routing table: here `table 205`.
- the additional routing table can be checked with

  ```
  ip route show table 205
  ```

  This routing table will be evaluated, and if a route is found, no further processing will happen: the main table won't be evaluated and a decision not matching the main table's content will happen. It will most likely show something similar to:

  ```
  default dev tun0 proto static
  ```

  But as it's about a tunnel `tun0` and routing the tunnel content must still allow normal routing of the tunnel envelope outside of itself, there should be somewhere (either in a rule or in this routing table) an exception to allow to reach the peer tunnel endpoint with normal ways (ie: using `dev wlp0s20f3`).

  Depending on the tunnel this exception is not always needed (eg: using WireGuard across a different network namespace than its tunnel envelope, but the interface is usually called `wg0` then) and can take different forms for different methods.